# how to remove image for iphone

Tags: iphone

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([[touch view] tag] == 1000) 
    {
        tap=YES;
        NSLog(@"tap");
        //[yourButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
        if(tap)
        {
            CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(p.x-113, p.y-113, 224.0f, 195.0f);
            myImagea = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
            [myImagea setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Enjoy Sunburst.png"]];
            myImagea.opaque = YES; // explicitly opaque for performance
            [self.view addSubview:myImagea];
            [myImagea release];                 
        }
        [pieMenu showInView:self.view atPoint:p]; 
}               
    else {
        NSLog(@" NO tap"); 
        // i want to remove image when user is not tapping
        //how to do that is myImagea.alpha=0 is the only options
    }
}
```

Comment: Has someone answered your question? Please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume your touch events code is correct...

To actually *remove* the object, you'd do something similar to this

```
[someObjectHere removeFromSuperview];
```

If you're trying to hide it, do what Jacob stated via the `hidden` property

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [`hidden`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW61) property of the `UIImageView` to `YES`.

If you would actually want to **remove** it, you can call `removeFromSuperview`.